# Generating Hashed Passwords in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, mosquitto

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask, but I am having an issue hashing passwords for MySql Backend. I am running mosquitto 1.4.3 broker and I have the [mosquitto-auth-plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) working on the same server. But I want to move the auth-plugin to a new server. So I created a admin program in C# to add users and access controls however I cant seem to the get the correct hash code for the password.

Has anyone implemented this or is there some resoucres available to create the correct hash?

I have tried this [Hash It Right](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiR5rzF3eTNAhUUM8AKHX39CQoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flockmedown.com%2Fhash-right-implementing-pbkdf2-net%2F&usg=AFQjCNEFopLN4oVp52jJIG5H_Evt-o7bVQ&sig2=BFrkIy0ePeFc8FcWcMn9RQ&cad=rjt)

```
private const int SaltByteLength = 12;
private const int DerivedKeyLength = 24;

public string CreatePasswordHash(string password)
{
    var salt = GenerateRandomSalt();
    var iterationCount = GetIterationCount();
    var hashValue = GenerateHashValue(password, salt, iterationCount);
    var iterationCountBtyeArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(iterationCount);
    var valueToSave = new byte[SaltByteLength + DerivedKeyLength + iterationCountBtyeArr.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, valueToSave, 0, SaltByteLength);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(hashValue, 0, valueToSave, SaltByteLength, DerivedKeyLength);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(iterationCountBtyeArr, 0, valueToSave, salt.Length + hashValue.Length, iterationCountBtyeArr.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(valueToSave);
}

private int GetIterationCount()
{
    return 901;
}

private static byte[] GenerateRandomSalt()
{
    var csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var salt = new byte[SaltByteLength];
    csprng.GetBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}

private static byte[] GenerateHashValue(string password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount)
{
    byte[] hashValue;
    var valueToHash = string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ? string.Empty : password;
    using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(valueToHash, salt, iterationCount))
    {
        hashValue = pbkdf2.GetBytes(DerivedKeyLength);
    }
    return hashValue;
}
```

Comment: I can try and guess, but there is absolutely no context for why this is tagged MQTT, Mosquttio. Update the question with why or I'll remove the tags

Comment: Is it just that they don't match when you call `CreatePasswordHash` again with the same password? Don't make the salt random. Quick edit -- I mean don't make it static for everyone. It should be tracked or tied to whatever account that password is for. It's just unique every time it gets called so it will never match when called twice.

Comment: Well, you can make it random upon initial generation, but you need to *store* that salt so that you can reuse it in the future when go to validate an incoming authentication request.

Comment: @KennethK. Hehe, I knew I needed to pre-empt that comment.

Comment: Yes I do store the salt along with the password I can get the passwords to match but plugin I am working with is looking for this format PBKDF2$sha256$901$x8mf3JIFTUFU9C23$Mid2xcgTrKBfBdye6W/4hE3GKeksu00+

Comment: @TyCobb Right after I clicked submit your edit popped up ;)

Comment: My bad, but I think PBKDF2$sha256$901$x8mf3JIFTUFU9C23$  is just appended to the password : standard$encoding$iterations$salt.  I will try that and check if it works.  Thanks for the quick reply's.

Answer (score 1):

will this make it easier for you?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Class1
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      byte[] HashValue;

      string MessageString = "This is the original message!";

      //Create a new instance of the UnicodeEncoding class to 
      //convert the string into an array of Unicode bytes.
      UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();

      //Convert the string into an array of bytes.
     byte[] MessageBytes = UE.GetBytes(MessageString);

      //Create a new instance of the SHA1Managed class to create 
      //the hash value.
      SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();

      //Create the hash value from the array of bytes.
      HashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);

      //Display the hash value to the console. 
      foreach(byte b in HashValue)
      {
         Console.Write("{0} ", b);
      }
   }
```